# WriteString to socket takes long pauses in the middle of sending a string?

Tags: socket

I use `mysock = SocketConnect[...]` to connect to a socket hosted by a c++ program.
Then, I send a string `mystr` to that socket via

```
WriteString[mysock, mystr];
SocketWaitNext[{mysock}];
```

The c++ program receives the data through a `recv` function with a `33ms` timeout. The program relies on receiving the complete string `mystr` in a single cycle (before timeout runs out) to work properly. Sometimes I notice that instead of the full string `mystr`, only a substring manages to be sent during one program cycle, while the rest of the string arrives during one of the following cycles. This means that `WriteString` starts to send data, then stops and takes a break (of longer than `33ms`) in the middle of it, and only later resumes to complete the data transfer.

> Is there a way to force `WriteString` to not take breaks while writing a single string?

Alternatively, is there a different function other than `WriteString` (perhaps undocumented) that can be used to transfer string data to a socket, and which would not take breaks during the transfer?

Comment: `WriteString[...,CigaretteBreak->False]`?? (I wish it were that simple)

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Tried it, does not seem to be valid Mathematica syntax... ;)